# PCM audio streaming over websocket

Tags: websocket, streaming, audio-streaming, pcm

I've been struggling with the following problem and can't figure out a solution. The provided java server application sends pcm audio data in chunks over a websocket connection. There are no headers etc. My task is to play these raw chunks of audio data in the browser without any delay. In the earlier version, I used audioContext.decodeAudioData  because I was getting the full array with the 44 byte header at the beginning. Now there is no header so decodeAudioData cannot be used. I'll be very grateful for any suggestions and tips. Maybe I've to use some JS decoding library, any example or link will help me a lot.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1) Your requirement "play these raw chunks of audio data in the browser without any delay" is not possible.   There is always some amount of time to send audio, receive it, and play it.  Read about the term "latency."  First you must get a realistic requirement.  It might be 1 second or 50 milliseconds but you need to get something realistic.

2) Web sockets use tcp.  TCP is designed for reliable communications, congestion control, etc.  It is not design for fast low latency communications.

3) Give more information about your problem.  Is you client and server communicating over the Internet or over a local Lan?  This will hugely effect your performance and design.

4) The 44 byte header was a wav file header.  It tells the type of data (sample rate, mono/stereo, bits per sample).  You must know this information to be able to play the audio.  *IF* you know the PCM type, you could insert it yourself and use your decoder as you did before.  Otherwise, you need to construct an audio player manually.

Streaming audio over networks is not a trivial task.

Comment: Thanks jaybers for ur response.

Comment: 1) About 50ms is acceptable
2) Binary data over websockets is pretty fast, so I was sure it would fit in
3) Local LAN
4) I've to convey voice data over to the browser in almost real time. My earlier version was conveying full wav file with header, but it increases latency.
The other options I'm digging info about is webRTC between client and server, but I'm not sure about it. Its a peer to peer technology.